# Should you downvote people for responding to questions that have duplicates?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I can only assume that's what happened to me on this question: [Is a resistor needed for LEDs in this beatbox project?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77626/is-a-resistor-needed-for-leds-in-this-beatbox-project/77627#77627)

Answer (score 5):

We shouldn't downvote because someone answered a duplicate question.  I downvote wrong, unclear, misleading, really badly written, and the like.

I have on rare occasions downvoted answers only because they shouldn't have been there.  I have only done this a few times, which I think have been when someone directly answered a homework problem.

However, in the particular case you linked to I don't think that's what is going on.  You were very sloppy with units.  I didn't go into this question before and didn't see your answer before and didn't do any of the downvotes, but I can understand the sentiment.  Seeing as you are a established user here, I probably would have left a comment and given you a chance to fix it, but others may have been less charitable or didn't know you have been around here a while.

You wrote:

(12 - Vf)/If = R
   (12 - 1.7)/0.020 = 515 Ω
   0.02 * 0.02 * 560 = 0.224 Watts

Really!!?  You should be ashamed of yourself for that.  The more I think about this, I might have downvoted and left a comment and removed the downvote when you fixed it.  Neatness, attention to detail, and above all clarity count for a lot.  Thinking about it more, if this question hadn't already been closed I'd go downvote your answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like people are voting based on your answer to the question, ignoring the duplicate part.

When we clear out old closed questions that will be wiped from your points anyway.